# Magento 2.3.0 - User roles and Permissions - module/extension installation issue

Tags: permissions, magento2.3, user-roles, magento2.3.0

I'm running magento 2.3.0 on php 7.1

I have two users each with a different user role/permissions created

```
Users     | User Role    | Role Resources (resource access)
----------|--------------|-------------------------------
Admin     |Administrator | All
dev       |Dev           | Custom (everything except permissions)
```

**Issue 1**

When a module was installed using the dev user and on logging in with the admin user the admin panel is completely messed up. Clearing cache did not help.

[image]

**Issue 2**

When logged in as the dev user the theme settings don't show up as they do when logged in as the admin user. As the below images show

View from dev user login 
(missing theme "wokiee" on left menu panel and within stores >> configuration)
[image]

View from admin user login 
(shows theme "wokiee" on left menu panel and stores >> configuration)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the first issue, please make sure that you have deployed the static content using **`static-content:deploy`** after the installation of the new module.
>
> On the second issue, make sure that **`resource access`** for **WOKIEE** is **`checked`** in the **`Role Resources`** of the **user role Dev**.

Comment: thank you, in the 1st issue, who runs that the static-content:deploy command? the dev user or the admin user, it's being installed by the dev user. In the 2nd issue is theme related, they haven't made it visible in role resources, so have taken that up with them.

Comment: static content deployment can be implemented through a **command line interface** using  **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`** (-f is used to force the deployment)

Comment: Does it matter which user runs the command? In the scenario I outlined a user (dev) other than the admin (admin)  installed the module which I assume is the cause of the issue.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. How did you install the module ? is it from the cli or from the admin panel?

Comment: File upload and then cli

Comment: alright. try the deploying the static content from the cli. hopefully, that will resolve the issue.